# Why are toposes usually denoted by $\mathcal E$?

Tags: category-theory, notation, soft-question, topos-theory

Why are toposes usually denoted by $\mathcal E$?

My guess would be that $\mathcal E$ stands for *elementary topos*. But I often see people denoting even Grothendieck toposes by $\mathcal E$ (in contexts where elementary toposes aren't discussed at all).

Comment: Are there other alphabets used for denoting toposes? I saw $T$ used (probably for "topos") as well. But then there's a problem when wanting to talk about several toposes: would you want to denote a topos by $U$ as in "let $T$ and $U$ be toposes"?

Comment: Maybe E for espace, or étale, or (less likely) ensemble.

Comment: I suppose it could also just be that $\mathcal C$ and $\mathcal D$ are usually arbitrary categories, so an author moves on to $\mathcal E$ for a topos. It seems to me that $\mathcal F$ is also used, which supports this theory.

Comment: I suspect it's $\cal E$ as in "ensemble", or $\cal E$ as in "$E \to B$ is a fibration".

Comment: In SGA4 the notation $E$ (and $E'$) seems most common, but occasionally $F$ ang $G$ are used as well (Exp IV Ex 9.1.6). Later on, $\mathcal{U}$ is used to denote an open subtopos. Nowadays, $\mathcal{S}$ is also common to denote a topos that should be thought of as a base topos.
I have no idea why the letter $E$ is used. Elementary toposes were only introduced after SGA4 was written, so I don't think that $E$ is inspired by "elementary".